# Angular 2: execute a function when the element appears on the screen

Tags: javascript, angular

With Angular 2, how can i execute a function when an element appears on the screen ? With good performance.

The context is the following: I have a loop, and when the element appears on the screen, I would like to execute a function from the controller.

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="#item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" item-right>
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
      <img [src]="item.imageSrc">
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

With Angular 1, I used ng-init and the function "article.getImg()"  and a different context (not to display all the images at once)

```
<img ng-show="article.hasImage" ng-init="article.imageLookedFor == false ? article.getImg() : null" ng-src="{{article.imageSrc}}" imageonloadheadline />
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<img>` element has a `load` event you can listen to:

```
<img [src]="item.imageSrc" (load)="doSomething()">
```

See also [Remove image when loading a new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352270/remove-image-when-loading-a-new-one/37352471#37352471)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was not accurate enough. I m looking for an event before load. i have some work to do before the image load.